# Verändern der Wort-Reihenfolge um eine Überschrift (Kurzbeschreibung, etc.) verständlicher zu machen?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Wenn wir in unserem [Issue-Tracking-System](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue-Tracking-System) neue Punkte einstellen, kommt es manchmal vor, dass durch Veränderung der Wort-Reihenfolge die Aussage klarer wird, der "Satz" dann aber irgendwie holprig klingt.

Beispiel:

- Pseudo-Langtext: "Das Programm gibt einen Hinweis aus, dass Komponenten möglicherweise abgewählt werden müssen, um die Aktualisierung erfolgreich abschließen zu können."
- Kurztext (A): "Hinweis auf mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten ausgeben"
- Kurztext (B): "Hinweis ausgeben auf mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten"

Ich bin der Meinung, dass Variante (B) für einen Kurztext verständlicher ist, mir kommt die Wortstellung aber etwas seltsam vor.

*Wie flexibel ist die deutsche Grammatik hier?*

Gibt's hier evtl. Regeln aus dem journalistischen Bereich (Zeitungs-Schlagzeilen etc.)?

**Hinweis:** Bei der Frage geht es mir nicht um den Inhalt des konkret angegebenen Beispiels, sondern darum, *wie falsch* die "holprige" Variante B ist, bzw. *ob* diese unter irgendwelchen Umständen grammatikalisch zulässig ist. (Die [Antwort von tohuwawohu](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/verandern-der-wort-reihenfolge-um-eine-uberschrift-kurzbeschreibung-etc-verst/2084#2084) finde ich schon sehr hilfreich.)

Comment: Ich würde ebenfalls die Variante B klar bevorzugen. Mag sein, das sie grammatikalisch unzulässig ist, aber ob das dann den Nutzern hilft...
Variante B kommt eben doch den Programmiersprachen-geschulten Hirn entgegen, weil es die Form Operation(Operand) imitiert.
Möglichweise kann man aber die Sache verbessern, indem man B umformuliert nach `Hinweis ausgeben: mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten`

Comment: Ich finde beides unverständlich, wenn gesagt werden soll, dass die Abwahl `nötig sein kann`. `Hinweis auf nötige Komponentenabwahl [aus]geben`. Alternativ: `Komponentenabwahlhinweis`. Dass der Hinweis irgendwie ausgegeben wird versteht sich m.E. implizit - sonst wäre es kaum ein Hinweis. Noch ein Vorschlag: `Auf nötige Komponentenabwahl hinweisen`.

Comment: Ist das jetzt eine Anforderung oder eine Fehlerbeschreibung?

Comment: Die theoretischen Abhandlungen in aller Ehre, aber überseht bitte nicht, wer die Zielgruppe (die LeserIn) eines solchen Issue-Eintrags vermutlich sein wird.

Comment: Das ist jetzt vielleicht etwas spät dafür, aber zielt die Frage eigentlich darauf ab, eine möglichst elegante Formulierung für den konkreten Fall zu finden (wie einige Kommentare suggerieren), oder geht es allgemein beispielhaft um die Frage, ob bei einer Konstruktion wie dieser eine Variante B korrekt und/oder zu bevorzugen ist bzw. es Regeln gibt? Ich habe mir nämlich einiges dazu überlegt, komme aber beim erneuten Lesen der Frage zum Schluss, dass diese möglicherweise nicht das ist, was ich eigentlich dachte ;)

Comment: @Oregon - Habe die Frage entsprechend mit Hinweis versehen.

Comment: Auch 9 Jahre später, beim erneuten Lesen der Frage, kam ich wieder auf den Widerspruch "möglicherweise nötige"/"mögliche". Der Hinweis, dass die Semantik ignoriert werden soll, leuchtet mir nicht ein - dann soll man den Pseudo-Langtext löschen. Dazu fällt mir auf, dass "erfolgreich abschließen" um das "erfolgreich" gekürzt werden könnte, pardon, erfolgreich gekürzt werden könnte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die beiden Kurzvarianten sind [Infinitivkonstruktionen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Infinitiv.html), die aber streng genommen grammatikalisch unvollständig sind: Es fehlt jeweils das Subjekt. Aus der Infinitivkonstruktion folgt, dass das Verb am Schluss steht (sogenannter "[Spannsatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungstyp.html#Anchor-Der-11481)"); daher entspricht Variante A eher dem Sprachgefühl und lässt sich ohne weiteres zu einem kompletten Satz ergänzen:

> "[Die Anwendung muss/soll einen] Hinweis auf [die] mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten ausgeben."

Da man sich also streng genommen sowieso schon außerhalb der Regeln der Satzgrammatik bewegt, ist es m. E. eher Geschmackssache, wie man die Überschrift formuliert. Dem Verständnis und der Lesbarkeit hilft es wohl eher, wenn der Satzbau eingehalten wird, der für den vollständigen Satz gelten würde (also Variante A) und ihm daher am ähnlichsten ist.

Ansonsten würde ich es eher funktional sehen: Wenn es gerade relevant ist, dass der *task* gerade mit der "Möglichkeit zur Abwahl von Komponenten" zusammenhängt, kann man das ohne weiteres vorziehen:

> Mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten: Hinweis ausgeben.

Richtlinien würde ich im journalistischen Bereich eher nicht erwarten. Ich könnte mir aber eher vorstellen, dass es gerade im technischen Bereich dazu Normen gibt (projektspezifisch, ISO oder vielleicht auch DIN): etwa um solche Überschriften automatisiert auszuwerten.

Comment: +1 für den Doppelpunkt! Damit ginge es auch noch kürzer: *"Hinweis ausgeben: mögliche Abwahl von Komponenten"*

Comment: @Takkat: das ist glaub ich exakt gleich lang ...

Comment: @Joachim: ist aber in der Reihenfolge wie B) ;)

Comment: Der Punkt ist inhaltlich aber, soweit ich es verstanden habe, der, dass die Abwahl der Komponenten nötig sein kann - nicht dass er möglich ist.

Comment: Jetzt klar +1, wo Martin klar gemacht hat, worum die Frage eigentlich ging ;)

Answer (score 4):

Mein Vorschlag, um den Langtext präzise wiederzugeben (im Sinne eines Issue-Tracking-Benutzers):

> Hinweis ausgeben: "Komponenten müssen möglicherweise abgewählt werden,
>   um die Aktualisierung erfolgreich abschließen zu können"

oder im Sinne "guter" Hinweismeldungen, die den Passiv vermeiden:

> Hinweis ausgeben: "Sie müssen möglicherweise Komponenten abwählen, um
>   die Aktualisierung erfolgreich abschließen zu können"

Durch die Trennung per Doppelpunkt und Anführungszeichen erkennt man auch, welcher Teil die Aufgabe und welcher der unveränderliche Text sein soll. Im Issue-Tracking geht es ja im wesentlichen nicht um "guten" Schreibstil und saubere Grammatik im klassischen Sinn, sondern um Eindeutigkeit und Unmissverständlichkeit.

**Update** nach dem neuen Hinweis von @Martin

Ich verstehe zwar nicht ganz die Absicht der Fragestellung, schließe mich aber unter diesen Umständen @tohuwawohu in der Begründung zu Variante (A) inhaltlich an.